# HTML Navbar items from Database in Asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, navigation, navbar

i am Editing an `HTML` template that has `Navbar` at top. i am able to edit the `navbar` items to the items in database but i am unable to change the `Number of Items` in Navbar menu because that coding is hardcoded in HTML. i want to create `Categories` in Database and show these in Navbar. these categories are not specific. 
coding for Navbar item in HTML is

```
<li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                    <li>
                                            <a href="#">Sliders</a>
                                            <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="basic-slider.html">Basic Slider</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="index.html">Right Info Slider</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="nivo-slider.html">Nivo Slider</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="accordion-slider.html">Accordion Slider</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="thumb-slider.html">Thumbnail Slider</a></li>

                                            </ul>
                                    </li>
```

these are 5 items in list and these are hardcoded in HTML. when i use database for this purpose my need is that i want all the database items in this Navbar no matter 5,6 or else. 
please suggest me what to do

Answer (score 0):

I assume you get data from `database` in a `datatable`. Loop through table and create `sublist` and append in the item you want.

You will need to set id of the `li` in which a `sublist` will appear

```
<li id="liDynamic" runat="server">
```

And Code to add a sublist in this `li`

```
HtmlGenericControl ul = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
liDynamic.Controls.Add(ul);
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
  HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");

  HtmlGenericControl anchor = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
  anchor.Attributes.Add("href", "page.htm");
  anchor.InnerText = dr["id"].ToString();
  li.Controls.Add(anchor);
  ul.Controls.Add(li);
}
```

Comment: if i use this method, the menu bar on all pages will be changed or just current page?

Comment: Where is you menu bar on master page ?